# HttpClient GetAsync response content is different from what Fiddler is giving me

Tags: c#, httpclient, fiddler

I'm running a GET request using `HttpClient.GetAsync`.

I am then using Fiddler to capture this request and see what it throws back:

```
    var response = await http.GetAsync("http://app.creditsafeuk.com/CSUKLive/webpages/CompanySearch/SearchResults.aspx?SelectedCountry=UK");
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    var html = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

This request is sent in my C# app and then captured with fiddler.

Even though it is the exact same request, the html in the response is different.

[Here is the HTML I'm getting from Fiddler](http://pastebin.com/yzVxMqJC)

[And this is the HTML that is being returned with the HttpClient](http://pastebin.com/3Rdv8Fxw)

Any help would be much appreciated, I just can't seem to figure out why I would get two separate versions even though Fiddler is capturing the same request my program is sending.

Comment: What kind of service is this and what kind of response does it give, is it a Rest API. 
I can see that C# code is not able to parse the `Javascript` code, which fiddler does, hence the difference. Can you try `WebClient` instead of `HttpClient`

Comment: Check - http://www.diogonunes.com/blog/webclient-vs-httpclient-vs-httpwebrequest/

Comment: It's a service that lets me query company information. I don't see how any of the `JavaScript` matters. The problem is, Fiddler is giving me what I need as a response, whereas my HttpClient isn't. Even though Fiddler is capturing what my HttpClient is getting. It makes zero sense to me.

Comment: Tried it using raw HttpWebRequests and I get the same issue.

Comment: I found a difference. There's an input tag called `__VIEWSTATE` which contains a long string of data which is getting cut off in my program's response, but not on Fiddler. Which is causing a lot of the HTML I need to not be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what it was.

Turns out, during debugging, the text visualiser actually cuts off parts of the string if it's too long. So, what I need is actually there, but the Text Visualiser wasn't giving it to me when I copied and pasted.